# how to use tabcontrol and tabpage in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to work just like this in asp.net and i haven't find the tabcontrol and tab page in asp.net.

```
TabPage[] tabPage = new TabPage[tabcount];
    for (int i = 0; i < tabPage.Length; i++)
        tabPage[i] = new TabPage();
        int count = 0;
        while (count < tabPage.Length)
        {
            dynamicTabControl.Controls.Add(tabPage[count]);

         count++;
        }
```

Comment: are you looking for the tab control for webform or window forms ? this TabPage control is only for WindowForm applications.

Comment: I am searching for the propery in asp.net to convert this c# code in asp.net.i am willing to find propery jus like tab control and tabpage property of c# in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Try using AjaxControl toolkit. It has built-in Tab Control.

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="Tab1" runat="server" HeaderText="Member" Width="100%">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <p>Tab 1</p>
  </ContentTemplate>
</ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="Tab2" runat="server" HeaderText="Info" Width="100%">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <p>Tab 2</p>
  </ContentTemplate>
</ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
</ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

**LINK to download:**  http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

In your Asp.net Project, Add Reference to the AjaxControlToolkit.dll and  Add following line
to your Aspx Page below the line `<%@ Page Language="C#"` on which you want to use tabs:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
```